# Use of enum without previous declaration & '___' (enum) does not name a type

Tags: c++

I've tried looking for other posts with the same issue as mine but could not find any.

The others have the same issue but the solutions they have I already went through and made sure I did that as well and I'm still having the issue.

There are three files in question here:

1. ItemType.h which includes:

```
#ifndef ITEMTYPE_H
#define ITEMTYPE_H

#include <iostream>

class ItemType {

private:
        int value;

public:
        enum Comparison;
        ItemType(); //Default Constructor
        Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
        int getValue() const; //Return the value instance variable
        void initialize(int num); //Initializes the data member by variable num
};
#endif
```

2. ItemType.cpp which includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ItemType.h"

//Enumeration
enum Comparison{GREATER, LESS, EQUAL};

//Methods
ItemType::ItemType() {
        value = 0;
}
ItemType::Comparison ItemType::compareTo(ItemType itemIn) {
        if (this->value < itemIn.getValue()) {
                return LESS;
        } else if (this->value > itemIn.getValue()) {
                return GREATER;
        } else {
                return EQUAL;
        }

}
int ItemType::getValue() const {
        return value;
}
void ItemType::initialize(int num) {
        ItemType a;
        a.value = num;
}
```

3. SortedLinkedList.cpp which is where i'm trying to utilize the enumeration. (There are other methods not shown that utilize ItemType.h & ListNode.h that is why they are included).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SortedLinkedList.h"
#include "ItemType.h"
#include "ListNode.h"

//Methods
int SortedLinkedList::searchItem(ItemType &itemIn) {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode *node = head;
        while (node != NULL) {
                count++;
                if(node->item.compareTo(itemIn.getValue() == 3)) {
                        return count;
                        break;
                } else {
                        node = node->next;
                }

        }
        return -1; //Could not find.
}
```

4. Here is the makefile just incase:

```
main: main.cpp SortedLinkedList.cpp ItemType.cpp ItemType.h SortedLinkedList.h ListNode.h
        g++ -o main main.cpp ItemType.cpp SortedLinkedList.cpp -I.
```

The compilation errors I'm receiving include:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp ItemType.cpp SortedLinkedList.cpp -I.
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
ItemType.h:12:7: error: use of enum ‘Comparison’ without previous declaration
  enum Comparison;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
ItemType.h:14:2: error: ‘Comparison’ does not name a type
  Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
  ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ItemType.cpp:2:0:
ItemType.h:12:7: error: use of enum ‘Comparison’ without previous declaration
  enum Comparison;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
ItemType.h:14:2: error: ‘Comparison’ does not name a type
  Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
  ^~~~~~~~~~
ItemType.cpp:5:6: error: ‘Comparison’ does not name an enumeration in ‘ItemType’
 enum ItemType::Comparison{GREATER, LESS, EQUAL};
      ^~~~~~~~
ItemType.cpp:11:11: error: ‘Comparison’ in ‘class ItemType’ does not name a type
 ItemType::Comparison ItemType::compareTo(ItemType itemIn) {
           ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from SortedLinkedList.h:4:0,
                 from SortedLinkedList.cpp:2:
ItemType.h:12:7: error: use of enum ‘Comparison’ without previous declaration
  enum Comparison;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
ItemType.h:14:2: error: ‘Comparison’ does not name a type
  Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
  ^~~~~~~~~~
SortedLinkedList.cpp: In member function ‘int SortedLinkedList::searchItem(ItemType&)’:
SortedLinkedList.cpp:27:17: error: ‘class ItemType’ has no member named ‘compareTo’
   if(node->item.compareTo(itemIn.getValue() == 3)) {
                 ^~~~~~~~~
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Just fyi, a [MCVE] of this could be done in as few as 11 lines like this: https://ideone.com/e3Xgr7

Comment: @scohe001 I apologize. I just did not want to leave out anything that could possibly be conflicting but now that you raise that point up, there are things I could have cut out like you mentioned.

Comment: No worries :) just remember for next time. Usually when I'm preparing to ask a question, I strip down the code piece by piece to see how small I can get it while still getting the error. Oftentimes that alone shows me what the error is. MCVE's are helpful for everybody.

Comment: Be aware that you never actually asked a question. It would be much better to start with the question (with a description of the situation), before going into how you searched but didn't find an answer. See also [ask] (in particular: "Introduce the problem before you post any code").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, your compiler explained everything to you, we just need to properly decode, compiler messages.
You are using only declared Comparison where it needs to be defined. So, quick solution would be to define Comparison in header file, before you use it.

```
#ifndef ITEMTYPE_H
#define ITEMTYPE_H

#include <iostream>

class ItemType {

    private:
        int value;

    public:
        enum Comparison{GREATER, LESS, EQUAL};// you dont need this in source file
        Comparison compareTo(ItemType item);// etc....
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution. Will mark as answered as soon as 'answer timer' ends. Thank you for the swift answer once again.

Answer (score 3):

If you for some reason would not like to share the possible values your `enum`s may take, just share the underlying type the `enum` uses so that the compiler knows how to do its job. Otherwise it doesn't know the size of the `enum`:

hpp:

```
class ItemType {
    ...
    enum Comparison : int;
```

cpp:

```
enum ItemType::Comparison : int {GREATER, LESS, EQUAL};
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of enum depends on the number (and values) of the enumerations you assign to it, so fully declare it in the header as

```
enum Comparison{GREATER, LESS, EQUAL};
```

It also defeats the purpose of enum to have the enumerations only visible to the class implementation when a member functions returns that enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the enum without any value (nor underlying type, see second solution), which is not valid C++; and in your cpp file, you declared a new enum with the same name since you forgot the enum's scope.

The easiest way to correct your problem is to fully declare the enumeration in the class :

```cpp
// in ItemType.h
class ItemType {

private:
        int value;

public:
        enum Comparison { GREATER, LESS, EQUAL };
        ItemType(); //Default Constructor
        Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
        int getValue() const; //Return the value instance variable
        void initialize(int num); //Initializes the data member by variable num
};
```

If you need to forward declare it, you will have to specify an underlying type so the compiler knows the size of the enum (and don't forget the scope) :

```cpp
// in ItemType.h
class ItemType {

private:
        int value;

public:
        enum Comparison : int;
        ItemType(); //Default Constructor
        Comparison compareTo(ItemType item); //Compare the value of item with the current object's value and return GREATER, LESS OR EQUAL.
        int getValue() const; //Return the value instance variable
        void initialize(int num); //Initializes the data member by variable num
};

// in ItemType.cpp

//Enumeration
enum ItemType::Comparison : int { GREATER, LESS, EQUAL };
```

Comment: "_You declared the enum without any value, which is not valid C++_" - isn't really correct though. Check out "Opaque enum declaration".

Comment: @TedLyngmo I actually used opaque enum declaration in my answer, but you're right, my first sentence is a bit misleading. I've fixed it.